# How to solve " Failed to read the 'rules' or 'cssRules' property from 'cssstylesheet' ", while trying to fetch the css in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, dom

I am trying to print a page. I am fetching the HTML and CSS for that same page using javascript. After we try to print the page, another tab opens up for the print and we can print from that page.

The styles in the print page needs to be different than the styles in the main page.

I am using the following steps to print the page :

1. I am fetching the HTML and CSS using javascript.
2. I am storing the HTML and CSS in a variable.
3. Then rendering the content in a new tab.
4. Then the print pop up opens up and we can use the print button to download/print the page.

I am getting the error in the 1st step while fetching the styles which are located in the same page.

The starting point of the whole app is from a route, (i.e. /factory).
If the website is running in localhost:3000, then the app is in localhost:3000/factory .

#### Function used for Printing

```js
const Print = () => {
    let printContents = document.getElementById("print").innerHTML;
    let stylesheets = Array.from(document.styleSheets).map((sheet) => {
      let rules = Array.from(sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules).map( //This line is throwing the error
        (rule) => rule.cssText
      );
      return rules.join("\n");
    });

    let combinedContent = `
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print</title>
          <style>
            ${stylesheets.join("\n")}
            @media print {
              .font{
                font-size:10px;
                margin-bottom:50px;
                color:green;
                text-align:center;
              }
              .page-break {
                page-break-before: always;
              }
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div>
            ${printContents}
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;

    // Open a single print window and populate it with the combined content
    let printWindow = window.open("", "_blank");
    printWindow.document.open();
    printWindow.document.write(combinedContent);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
  };
```

#### Image of the folder that includes both CSS and JS

[Image of the folder that includes both CSS and JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZlii.png)